# Get parent objects based on child object field value

Tags: c#, linq

I need to return all objects that have child objects with a certain field != null.

NOTE: `EpicStoryId` is nullable int (as in 'int?')

I have tried:

```
return _context.Features
            .Where(x => x.UserStories.Any(us => us.EpicStoryId.HasValue) 
                && x.Id == Id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

and I have tried:

```
return _context.Features
            .Where(x => x.UserStories.Any(us => us.EpicStoryId != null) 
                && x.Id == Id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

and for good measure:

```
return _context.Features
            .Where(x => x.UserStories.Any(us => us.EpicStoryId.HasValue == false) 
                && x.Id == Id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

and finally:

```
return _context.Features
            .Where(x => x.UserStories.Any(us => us.EpicStoryId > 0) 
                && x.Id == Id)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

But none of these work. It's still returning every 'Feature' with `Id=Id` regardless if a child has a value for `EpicStoryId` or not. (FYI, I checked the data and there ARE null values for some `EpicStoryId`'s.)

sample data:

[image]

Comment: You're using `.Any` inside the `.Where` query, which will return `true` if any one `EpicStoryID` has a value.

Comment: Your query only checks whether the parent has *any* stories with non-null EpicStoryIds. So if it has one user story with an EpicStoryId and one without, that feature will still be selected. Is that deliberate? It would help if you'd show sample data and desired results.

Comment: There is no reason why what you have tried shouldn't work. So you need to add more detail to determine exactly where the problem is, because it's not in the code you've shown.

Comment: I added sample data. Desired results are described in first sentence of post. Based on sample data, it should return one(1) 'Feature' not both since one has EpicStoryId == null

Comment: @Beau - I hope `EpicStoryId ` in first sequence is `0,0,4` in that case my query should give you expected result because `x.UserStories.All(us => us.EpicStoryId.HasValue)` will return `true` for this and `0 0 Null` will return false.

Comment: NO, EpicStoryId in first sequence is '4'. Guess you didn't read the question well.

Comment: @Beau - In that case you need to format your sample data cz its all messed up. Also, clarify does your sample data represents `UserStories`?

Comment: posted a pic of the sample data. Does that help? Yes,userStories

Comment: just curious how query looks like in sql profiler

Comment: It's not clear what are you asking for. The picture shows **one** FeatureId = 2, so should it be included or not?

Comment: @Beau - Based on your query I assume you have `Id` column in `Features` too, and do you want to select row with id - `13`  in this sample data cz it has `EpicStoryId` as not null?

Comment: What I was trying to do was, only include UserStories that don't have NULL for EpicStoryID... yes, perhaps I didn't word this well enough. My apologies.

Comment: Didn't you ask this question last week?

Answer (score 2):

`Any` will return true i any 1 `EpicStoryId` has value so your your condition is failing.

`All` should do:-

```
return _context.Features
               .FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserStories.All(us => us.EpicStoryId.HasValue) 
                    && x.Id == Id);
```

Comment: This didn't work. It retrieved nothing now. I'm adding more to the original question

Comment: @Beau - It will return only if all `EpicStoryId` are not null. I guess you didn't explained your question well. Will update accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return all objects then don't use `FirstOrDefault()`, use combination of `.Where()` and `.ToList()` methods :

For ***any*** of us EpicStoryIds are not null use :

```
return _context.Features
            .Where(x => x.Id == Id && x.UserStories.Any(us => us.EpicStoryId.HasValue))
            .ToList();
```

For ***all*** of us EpicStoryIds are not null you can use  :

```
return _context.Features
            .Where(x => x.Id == Id && x.UserStories.All(us => us.EpicStoryId.HasValue))
            .ToList();
```

If you want to return list of `UserStories` and not `Features`, you can use :

```
return _context.Features
            .Where(x => x.Id == Id)
            .SelectMany(x => x.UserStories
              .Where(us => us.EpicStoryId.HasValue))
            .ToList();
```